# How to create a customized dimension in linespace

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

```
X_new = np.linspace(1, len(cumsum), num=len(cumsum)).reshape(-1,1)
plt.ylabel('Explained Variance')
plt.xlabel('Dimensions')
plt.plot(X_new, cumsum, 'b-')
```

The above code gives a graph with x -axis starting from 0,100,200,300...800. But I want to shows X axis label as 0,50,100,150,200,250.....800. How do i do that. I tried with retstep =True and step =50 but could not obtain the desired label in X-axis with np.linespace()

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`plt.xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) method:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 8001, 50))
```